# ERROR - Cannot find 'test.bcf'! when trying to use citation

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I tried tried to run this tex file but the citation doesn't show

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}

\title{Your Topic}
\date{\today}
\author{Max Mustermann}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{How To Use Citations}
This is a citation~\cite{barabasi1999emergence}. 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

The bib file for reference is as below:

```
  @article{barabasi1999emergence,
  title={Emergence of scaling in random networks},
  author={Barab\'asi, Albert-L\'aszl\'o and Albert, R\'eka},
  journal={Science},
  volume={286},
  number={5439},
  pages={509--512},
  year={1999},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
```

I tried to use `pdflatex` → `biber` → `pdflatex` → `view pdf`, but it shows:

> Process started
> INFO - This is Biber 2.15 INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
> ERROR - Cannot find 'test.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1
> Process exited with error(s)

If I only use `pdflatex`, it shows:

> Citation `barabasi1999emergence' on page 1 undefined on input line 25.
> (test.bbl) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLHqv.png) (test.aux)
> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

I don't know where I do wrong. I also tried changing the settings here to `biber %`
[image]

Or even add`\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`but doesn't work. Although I don't think it has anything to do with the situation. Please help.

Comment: You are using classical BibTeX (`\bibliographystyle{plain}`) and not `biblatex` (`\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}`), so you must run BibTeX on your document and not Biber. You need to have `bibtex %.aux` in the *Bib(la)tex* field highlighted in your screenshot.

Comment: Wow it really worked. Thank you so much!